# Font Awesome 4.1 urls

Tags: svg, font-awesome, truetype, woff, eot

Anybody knows the absolute URL of the new 4.1 Font Awesome sources (eot, woff, ttf, svg) ?

I want to insert as `@font-face` in CSS like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W5Eh2/24/), I don't want to download the sources or use the minified CSS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for these link?

- http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0
- http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0
- http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0
- http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0